# Записать и считать обьект в файл С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Здравствуйте, имеется массив обьектов `static vector<MobilePhone*> devices;`. Как можно записать все что внутри в бинарный файл, чтобы при повторном запуске программы можно было это считать ? Спасибо !

Comment: Что из себя представляет MobilePhone?

Comment: а нужно именно "бинарный файл"? я бы сохранял в какой-нибудь json/yaml или xml на худой конец.

Comment: @Unick , MobilePhone Это мой класс, указатели на обьекты которого лежат в векторе

Comment: В бинарном виде сохранять может быть или не безопасно или трудоёмко. Т.к. если у вас есть в классе не только POD типы, то придётся отдельно обрабатывать указатели и т.д. Чтобы после загрузки все данные были валидные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Какого-то простого способа нет. Нужно самому реализовать запись класса в файл, отдельно поле за полем, и соответственно - считывания. И вызывать в цикле над вектором это считывание(запись).